# Send Alert mail via script

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm in an internship and I have to monitor specific ports of specific switch. I have decided to send email alerts if a port is disconnected several times in a row. For that, I have tested this Query in MySQL CLI :

```
SELECT IF ((SELECT COUNT(message) FROM devices, ports, eventlog 
WHERE hostname = "HOSTNAME" 
AND message = "ifOperStatus: down -> up" 
AND ports.ifName = "0/8" and datetime >= now() - INTERVAL 45 MINUTE) >= 4, "ok", "false");
```

If the eventlog message "ifOperStatus: down -> up" appears 4 times or +, the query returns "ok".

Now I'd like to write a script who connects to my database, execute the previous query and if it returns "ok", send an email. I will set a cron job to execute the script automatically every minute.

The matter is that, I don't know how to do that. I have tested this :

[ScriptCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tkWw.png)

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
//connect to database
$dbconnect = mysql_connect('HOSTNAME', 'DB_Name', 'Passwd');
$result = $dbconnect->query(
  SELECT IF ((SELECT COUNT(message) FROM devices, ports, eventlog 
  WHERE hostname = "HOSTNAME" 
  AND message = "ifOperStatus: down -> up" 
  AND ports.ifName = "0/8" and datetime >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) >= 4, "good", 
  "false"
);

//if there are any records matching this query we send an email listing each one using 'part_no' as the identifier in this case
if ($result = 'good') {
  $email = 'destination_mail';
  $subject = "Port alert";
  $message = "Port go down too much";
  if (mail($email, $subject, $message)) {
    // mail successfully sent
  } else {
    // mail unsuccessfull
  }
}
```

I'm really bad in scripting. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum.  Unfortunately "doesn't work" doesn't help.  Please describe the expected behaviour and the actual behaviour.  This will help you gain useful answers.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Don’t show us _images_ of code, but put the code directly into your question, in text form and properly formatted.

Comment: `if($result="good")` - that would be an assignment, not a comparison.

Comment: CBroe is right. The condition will always be true (because `"good"` evaluates to `true`). So the mail would be send in any case. Is that your problem ?

Comment: Thanks for answers. No my problem is that i can't send mail anyway due my code i think

Comment: when a exec php file :                                                   
librenms@adminsys:~/scripts$ php portAlert.php
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'COUNT' (T_STRING), expecting ')' in /opt/librenms/scripts/portAlert.php on line 4

Comment: Surround your query with quotes `'`